# How do I turn off the Life Extractor machine?

Tags: little-runmo-the-game

In [*Little Runmo - The Game*](https://juhosprite.itch.io/little-runmo), I came across a machine with an on/off switch that processes extra lives. In [the original Runmo animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErQHVUQ6QCk) he was able to turn off the machine ([8:07](https://youtu.be/ErQHVUQ6QCk?t=487)), but I can't find a way to deactivate it in the game.

How do I turn off the Life Extractor machine?

[image: On/Off switch for the Life Extractor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot turn off the Life Extractor machine in *Little Runmo - The Game*. However, The character that Runmo met in the animation after turning off the machine, (Temp King), can still be met in the game.

> First, collect all 7 coins scattered in different areas. Then, head to the throne room. Go past the throne while avoiding the Dring King's swipes. Go through a riding door and keep going right until you see a locked door. The lock will break if you have all 7 coins. The coin locations [can be seen in this video](https://youtu.be/xlLNth9N_qo?t=1058).